# Looping through JSON Data for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to access data in this JSON (see below) file such as type, properties, etc. using:

```
data = new google.maps.Data();
var json = data.loadGeoJson('insert-url-here');

for (var i=0; i < json.length; i++) {
      var obj = json[i];
      console.log(obj.coordinates);
}
```

I get an error on the first line of the for loop `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. I want to zoom into the object by reading its `coordinates` value.

```
google.maps.addListener(data, 'click', function () {
  obj.setZoom(10);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

JSON sample:

```
"features": [{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 18, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -34.397, 150.644 ] }
```

Comment: json is in js object format, instead of a regular for loop try a for in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: You need to see the JSON object as a tree. It's hierarchical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually retrieve the `coordinates` property you need to do this:

```js
var json = {"features": [{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 18, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -34.397, 150.644 ]}}}]} 
                          
document.write(json.features[0].properties.geometry.coordinates);
```

How is this JSON build

```
object 
    - property -> features (Array, length: 1)
      [ Object
         - property -> properties (Object)
            - property -> geometry (Object)
               - property -> coordinates (Array, length: 2)
      ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation regarding the structure of JSON. It really helps. But is my for loop statement okay? For some reason still can't get it to work.

Comment: @kolor You can't loop this data structure the way you want. To retrieve the coordinates from the JSON use my code, no need for looping here, unless it returns more objects within the features property.

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = data.loadGeoJson('insert-url-here');
```

the json variable here is returning as a undefined object causing the error. Also better use another variable name

whenever you get the json returned, you can use something like eval() to return a javascript object. so that you can access coordinates using json.features[0].properties.coordinates

features here is an array so you need to go through them